# How to bundle Spacy model using Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, spacy-3

This is the command I am executing while generating the executable.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "C:/Users/23010001/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/xx_ent_wiki_sm/xx_ent_wiki_sm-3.5.0/*;spacy/model" -w Main.py
```

I have tried using this method, but still no luck.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

This is environment informaiton.

```
spaCy version    3.5.2
Location         C:\Users\23010001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy
Platform         Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
Python version   3.11.1
Pipelines        en_core_web_sm (3.5.0), xx_ent_wiki_sm (3.5.0)
```

But once the executable is created, it cannot locate the model.
I am new in this arena.
Appreciate any help in this regard.
Thank you all.